# Maven: Non-parseable POM unrecognized tag error appearing on every tag

Tags: java, spring, maven

I feel like a true rookie, and i'm truly stumped. I might need to take a break too -_-

I keep getting this error for my code, "Non-parseable POM H:\Desktop\com.objectdb.tutorial.spring_KUmoduleMarks\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag:
'dependency' (position: START_TAG seen ...\n       ... @45:29)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.objectdb.tutorial.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>Guestbook</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Guestbook</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>objectdb</id>
        <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.objectdb.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.3</version>
<!--            <version>2.6.2_02</version>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>Entity</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-stereotype</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.objectdb.Enhancer</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>guest.Guest</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <finalName>Guestbook</finalName>
</build>

</project>
```

Have i used the incorrect syntax? Is there a crucial step/concept i have completely missed?

Comment: Is the missing "</project>" closing tag just because you didn't copy paste the whole pom?

Comment: yes, my bad. I didn't paste the entire pom. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem to me seems to be this section:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>Entity</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
//Closing tag?
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<dependency>` tag for `javax.persistence:Entity` is not closed.